# Why is it "an Asia" but not "a Asia"?

Tags: word-usage

> There was an Asia Minor and an Asia Major located in modern-day Iraq.
>   
> [Classical antiquity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia#Classical_antiquity)

We use "an" when the word is starting with *a, e, i, o, u*. (**e.g.** an elephant) Second rule is if the word pronounced directly *a, e, i, o, u* we cannot use "an". (**eg.** a unicorn)

**Asia** in this case starts with *a*, and is pronounced directly as *a*.

Comment: By the way, I know *a Asia* is uncommon. I'm looking for a technical answer.

Comment: You have misstated the rule.  The rule is to use *an* before vowel sounds and *a* before consonant sounds, like /ði/ and /ðə/: the spelling is immaterial, because this is strictly a sound-rule. See *sandhi* for details. See also [When should I use “a” vs “an”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/152) and [Do you use “a” or “an” before acronyms?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1016) and [When should I use “a” versus “an” in front of a word beginning with the letter h?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/629) on ELU, which combined make up the most frequently asked question ever there.

Comment: Can you quickly answer me? I still can't find the mistake.

Comment: 'Unicorn' is misleading you because it's pronounced 'You-nicorn' - as tchrist says, it's a sound-rule. Compare 'An update', 'An umbrella' etc.

Comment: @peterG But if it's a sound rule, why is the /j/ at the beginning of unicorn considered a consonant? After all, it has none of the phonetic or articulatory attributes of a consonant! –